# Why does my power diode have 4 terminals?

Tags: diodes, power-electronics

I am using a high voltage diode (APTDF400U120G) to freewheel an inductor in a switching circuit. It has four terminals, two for either side of the diode.  I cannot figure out why this is.  If I only connect to one input and one output terminal will the rating of the diode be lowered from the listed 400A? What is the purpose of four terminals?

Comment: Post a picture and a link to the datasheet so we all know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

For both redundancy and reduced overall inductance. You really don't want to have a loose connection being a single point of failure in a 400 A circuit!